# HighCharts: How to change style of bottom line color

Tags: highcharts

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qg46v.png)
I want to change the color of the line to black one as you can see above

this is my code of that part which draws highcharts.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FJL8s.png)
I thought I needed to fix it in the type:'area' and
I've tried to set the type area and read API as much as I can but I couldn't solove the problem

plz anybody help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line that you want to change is a `yAxis` gridline. Since there is no API option to change a single gridline, you need to get access to the proper SVG element and change its attribute.

```
  chart: {
    events: {
      load: function() {
        const yAxis = this.yAxis[0];
        const firstTick = yAxis.ticks[yAxis.tickPositions[0]];

        firstTick.gridLine.attr({
          stroke: '#000',
          'stroke-width': 1
        });
      }
    }
  }
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/hLasqxer/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGElement#attr

Comment: I made it !! Thank u so much ~! I really appreciate ur good answer and intelligence !!